# std::regex: Ubuntu(15.10)-Clang++ produces much more performant binaries than Debian-8-Clang++ (both v.3.4.)

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, ubuntu, debian

I have created a test-program, which measures the performance of `std::regex` while parsing csv-data:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <chrono>
#include <regex>
#include <set>
#include <iomanip>

#define DEFAULT_REGEX                                 \
    R"(^((?:[^\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\\;]|\\\\|\\;)*);)"   \
    R"((L|P|D|DN|R|W|LS|PS|RS|LU|PU|RU|LK|PK|RK|F);)" \
    R"(((?:[^\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\\;]|\\\\|\\;)*);)"    \
    R"(((?:[^\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\\;]|\\\\|\\;)*);)"    \
    R"(((?:[^\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\\;]|\\\\|\\;|\\:)*))" \
    R"((?:;((?:[^\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\\;])"             \
    R"(|\\\\|\\;|\';\')*))?$)"

struct results_t {
    std::string address;
    std::string command;
    std::string client;
    std::string param;
    std::string value;
    std::string error;
};

void std_regex(std::size_t num, const std::string &str, results_t &res) {
    std::smatch pieces;
    static const std::regex pattern{DEFAULT_REGEX};
    for (auto i = 0u; i < num; i++) {
        bool matched = std::regex_match(str, pieces, pattern);
        if (!(matched && pieces.size() == 7)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("ERROR");
        }
    }
    res.address = pieces[1];
    res.command = pieces[2];
    res.client = pieces[3];
    res.param = pieces[4];
    res.value = pieces[5];
    res.error = pieces[6];
}

std::size_t get_median(const std::multiset<std::size_t> &measured_values) {
    std::size_t i = 0;
    std::size_t median = 0;
    for (auto it = measured_values.cbegin();; it++, i++) {
        double tmp = static_cast<double>(measured_values.size() - 1) / 2.0;
        if (i == floor(tmp)) {
            median = *it;
        }
        if (i == ceil(tmp)) {
            median += *it;
            break;
        }
    }
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(static_cast<double>(median) / 2.0 + 0.5);
}

std::size_t get_avg(const std::multiset<std::size_t> &measured_values) {
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(
        std::accumulate(measured_values.cbegin(), measured_values.cend(), 0) /
            static_cast<double>(measured_values.size()) +
        0.5);
}

int main(void) {
    constexpr std::size_t num = 100000;
    constexpr std::size_t measure_num = 250;
    std::string str = "zzz\\\\bbbb;L;babaa;bubu\\;cc;vvvv;asdff";

    std::multiset<std::size_t> measured_values;
    results_t res;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < measure_num; i++) {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std_regex(num, str, res);
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        measured_values.insert(
            std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start)
                .count());
    }

    std::cout << *measured_values.cbegin() << ";"           // min
              << *measured_values.crbegin() << ";"          /// max
              << get_avg(measured_values) << ";"            // average
              << get_median(measured_values) << std::endl;  // median
}
```

With Ubuntu 15.10 and Debian 8, the code was compiled (without errors or warnings) with:

```
clang++-3.4 -DCOMPILER='"clang++-3.4"' -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -Wextra -DNDEBUG -O3 -mtune=native -march=native -std=c++1y -o eval_clang_3_4 eval.cpp
```

As expected, this program shows different times, if different compilers are used. E.g. the performance is becoming better, if you use g++5.2 instead of g++4.9.

But this evaluation-program also shows a interesting feature: It produces much worser times, if you use clang++-3.4 on Debian 8 instead of Ubuntu 15.10. The software runs both times on the same machine(Intel i7-3770k and 8GB RAM) and in both cases, clang++-3.4 is used.

The evaluation is executed 250-times and in the following lines, you see the statistic of this measurements.

Here are the measured values on Debian 8: (min;max;avg;median)

```
691244;1160628;713112;700739
```

Here are the measured values on Ubuntu 15.10: (min;max;avg;median)

```
198484;290986;202656;200637
```

I would not care about this, if the difference would be about 10 or 20%, but in this case, the difference is about 350%.

Why is there such a big difference, in exectuing this binary?

Comment: It looks like the regex for `error` is (ironically) wrong. It has ... strange parentheses. Did you really mean `(|\\|\;|';')*` there? (Answer: no)

Comment: No the regex is not wrong, the parenthesis on the left contains to R"(

Comment: I know. You missed my point.

Comment: In case you're interested, I have an alternative implementation that's both more maintainable and a lot faster: http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/cb17d050-694b-4df3-9ee3-736d133728e7/test.html

Answer (score 3):

I' have done some more benchmarking, elaborating on the tests in [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33478177/85371).

I've created alternative parser implementations in

- Spirit Qi (v2.x)
- Spirit X3 (c++14 only, experimental)
- A manual parser (written c++14 style, but could very easily be made c++03)

### Performance results:

- Interactive graph: [clang3.6-libcxx-qi.html](http://tinyurl.com/p743tz3) [image]
- Interactive graph: [clang3.6-libcxx-x3.html](http://tinyurl.com/qcudtbw) [image]
- Interactive graph: [clang3.6-qi.html](http://tinyurl.com/ob2lov8) [image]
- Interactive graph: [clang3.6-x3.html](http://tinyurl.com/qhvlcom) [image]
- Interactive graph: [gcc5-qi.html](http://tinyurl.com/nttyan6) [image]
- Interactive graph: [gcc5-x3.html](http://tinyurl.com/nkeqkyh) [image]

Clearly, the handwritten parser is hand-down the winner, regardless of compiler used.

Spirit X3 comes in a clear second.

Spirit Qi *exactly* matches `std_regex` performance, except on `libc++`, because there `std_regex` is just slow.

### Summary:

I'd suggest going with either Spirit or the manual parser, because:

- the regular expression is a nightmare to maintain (in fact [I already spotted errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477982/stdregex-ubuntu15-10-clang-produces-much-more-performant-binaries-than-de#comment54742841_33477982))
- all three alternatives give you much more useful results (in that escape sequences are *actually interpreted*, so you don't have to process these again)
- the X3 grammar is very easy to maintain

### Alternative 1: Spirit X3

This is my personal favourite if you can afford to use an experimental boost library that requires C++14. Looking at the code you will see why:

```
void spiritX3(const std::string &payload, results_t &res) {

    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    auto escaping = [](auto&& set) { return ('\\' >> char_(set)) | (print - char_(set)); };
    auto text     = escaping(";\\");

    symbols<unused_type> cmds;
    cmds += "L", "P", "D", "DN", "R", "W", "LS", "PS", "RS", "LU", "PU", "RU", "LK", "PK", "RK", "F";

    auto address_ = *text;
    auto command_ = raw [ cmds ];
    auto client_  = *text;
    auto param_   = *text;
    auto value_   = *escaping(";:\\"); // note the ':'
    auto error_   = *("'" >> char_(';') >> "'" | escaping(";\\"));

    auto attr = std::tie(res.address, res.command, res.client, res.param, res.value, res.error);

    if (!parse(
            payload.begin(), payload.end(),
            address_ >> ';' >> command_ >> ';' >> client_ >> ';' >> param_ >> ';' >> value_ >> -(';' >> error_),
            attr)) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("ERROR");
    }
}
```

### Alternative 2: Spirit Qi

This is basically a direct reflection of the X3 grammar, but with some macro abuse to make up of the limitations of Qi (you could also "fix" it by having more repeated code).

Spirit Qi has the benefits of being fully C++03 compatible and part of stable boost for nearly a decade:

```
void spiritQi(const std::string &payload, results_t &res) {

    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

#define ESCAPING(set) (('\\' >> char_(set)) | (print - char_(set)))
#define TEXT *ESCAPING(";\\")

    symbols<char, unused_type> cmds;
    cmds += "L", "P", "D", "DN", "R", "W", "LS", "PS", "RS", "LU", "PU", "RU", "LK", "PK", "RK", "F";

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    rule<It, std::string()> address_ = TEXT;
    rule<It, std::string()> command_ = raw [ cmds ];
    rule<It, std::string()> client_  = TEXT;
    rule<It, std::string()> param_   = TEXT;
    rule<It, std::string()> value_   = *ESCAPING(";:\\"); // note the ':'
    rule<It, std::string()> error_   = *("'" >> char_(';') >> "'" | ESCAPING(";\\"));

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((address_)(command_)(client_)(param_)(value_)(error_))

#undef TEXT
#undef ESCAPING

    auto attr = std::tie(res.address, res.command, res.client, res.param, res.value, res.error);

    if (!parse(
            payload.begin(), payload.end(),
            address_ >> ';' >> command_ >> ';' >> client_ >> ';' >> param_ >> ';' >> value_ >> -(';' >> error_),
            attr)) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("ERROR");
    }
}
```

### Alternative 3: Manual Parsing Code

This code doesn't take any dependencies, being fully standard c++.

Of course, it will take more coding, as you will see.

We made it 'selfcontained' by using C++14 lambdas, but it's "easy" to write up the equivalent parsing code in C++03, that should lead to the same performance after optimization.

```
void manual(const std::string &payload, results_t &res) {

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    It       it  = payload.begin();
    It const end = payload.end();

    auto consume = [&](char const* escape_set, std::string& into, auto&& specials) {
        while (it != end)
            if (!specials(into)) switch (*it) {
                case '\\':
                    if (++it != end && strchr(escape_set, *it))
                        into += *it++;
                    else
                        throw "invalid escape";
                    break;
                default:
                    if (isprint(*it) && !strchr(escape_set, *it))
                        into += *it++;
                    else
                        return true;
            }
        return true;
    };

    auto escaping = [&](char const* escape_set, std::string& into) {
        return consume(escape_set, into, [](std::string&) { return false; });
    };
    auto matched = [&](char const* what) {
        auto saved = it;
        auto wit = what;
        while (*wit) {
            if (it != end && *wit == *it)
                { ++wit; ++it; }
            else {
                it = saved;
                // throw "expected: '" + std::string(what);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    };

    auto expect = [&](char const* what) {
        if (!matched(what))
            throw "expected: '" + std::string(what);
        return true;
    };

    auto cmd = [&](std::string& into) {
        static const char *const cmds[] = { "D", "DN", "F", "L", "LK", "LS", "LU", "P", "PK", "PS", "PU", "R", "RK", "RS", "RU", "W" };
        for (auto cmd : cmds)
            if (matched(cmd)) {
                into.assign(cmd);
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    };

    bool ok =  escaping(";\\", res.address) && expect(";")
            && cmd(res.command)                 && expect(";")
            && escaping(";\\",  res.client)     && expect(";")
            && escaping(";\\",  res.param)      && expect(";")
            && escaping(":;\\", res.value);

    auto squoted_semicolon = [&](std::string& into) {
        if (!matched("';'"))
            return false;
        into += ';';
        return true;
    };

    ok &= (it==end) || (expect(";") && consume(";\\", res.error, squoted_semicolon));

    if (!ok)
        throw std::runtime_error("ERROR");
}
```

### Sample output

The output off the configuration clang 3.6 with libc++:

```
---- parsed with regex:
address: zzz\\bbbb
command: L
client:  babaa
param:   bubu\;cc
value:   vvvv
error:   asd';'ff
---- parsed with manual parser (note: unescaping taken care of):
address: zzz\bbbb
command: L
client:  babaa
param:   bubu;cc
value:   vvvv
error:   asd;ff
---- parsed with spirit Qi (note: unescaping taken care of):
address: zzz\bbbb
command: L
client:  babaa
param:   bubu;cc
value:   vvvv
error:   asd;ff
clock resolution: mean is 16.9379 ns (40960002 iterations)

benchmarking std_regex
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 4.968 ms
mean: 15.2716 μs, lb 14.8763 μs, ub 16.1072 μs, ci 0.95
std dev: 2.81028 μs, lb 1668.21 ns, ub 5.63468 μs, ci 0.95
found 1 outliers among 100 samples (1%)
variance is severely inflated by outliers

benchmarking spirit Qi
collecting 100 samples, 7 iterations each, in estimated 1780.1 μs
mean: 2.15209 μs, lb 2.06754 μs, ub 2.22874 μs, ci 0.95
std dev: 412.372 ns, lb 369.921 ns, ub 453.462 ns, ci 0.95
found 0 outliers among 100 samples (0%)
variance is severely inflated by outliers

benchmarking manual
collecting 100 samples, 37 iterations each, in estimated 1705.7 μs
mean: 451.902 ns, lb 448.665 ns, ub 459.504 ns, ci 0.95
std dev: 23.7123 ns, lb 7.42683 ns, ub 41.7546 ns, ci 0.95
found 2 outliers among 100 samples (2%)
variance is severely inflated by outliers
```

Answer (score 1):

The benchmark looks fatally flawed, because you store the samples in `set`, not `multiset`.

I'll post a fixed version with Nonius (micro-benchmark framework) and show difference between GCC 5 and Clang 3.6

### Simple Comparison:

Noniused: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13082145/ (see below)

- GCC/libstdc++ Output - **[interactive graph](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/73c6fe81-490c-45f7-90ef-f26e78b0de6e/gcc.html)**

  ```
  clock resolution: mean is 16.4758 ns (40960002 iterations)

  benchmarking testcase
  collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 2.3705 ms
  mean: 2.65143 μs, lb 2.56397 μs, ub 3.0819 μs, ci 0.95
  std dev: 856.395 ns, lb 13.87 ns, ub 2.04304 μs, ci 0.95
  found 4 outliers among 100 samples (4%)
  variance is severely inflated by outliers
  ```
- Clang/libc++ output **[interactive graph](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/81ba1590-73f4-449a-a44b-80708c4fb00e/clang.html)**

  ```
  clock resolution: mean is 16.2365 ns (40960002 iterations)

  benchmarking testcase
  collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 5.1507 ms
  mean: 14.5007 μs, lb 14.1065 μs, ub 15.6277 μs, ci 0.95
  std dev: 3.16854 μs, lb 1395.03 ns, ub 6.91175 μs, ci 0.95
  found 1 outliers among 100 samples (1%)
  variance is severely inflated by outliers
  ```
- Clang/libstdc++ output **[interactive graph](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/37e958d0-570a-46d9-bfe9-13ab8435a6e9/clang-libstdcpp.html)**

  ```
  clock resolution: mean is 16.7234 ns (40960002 iterations)

  benchmarking testcase
  collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 2.468 ms
  mean: 3.48597 μs, lb 3.39304 μs, ub 3.92522 μs, ci 0.95
  std dev: 879.913 ns, lb 74.8209 ns, ub 2.09227 μs, ci 0.95
  found 8 outliers among 100 samples (8%)
  variance is severely inflated by outliers
  ```

### Conclusions?

It's obvious that

- measuring this micro benchmark noise-free is hard
- libc++ seems to be roughly 2x slower in combination with clang
- using clang/gcc seems less of an influence (although there is some difference on average, the the variance makes it hard to say it's relevant)

### Code Listing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nonius/benchmark.h++>
#include <nonius/main.h++>
#include <regex>

#define DEFAULT_REGEX                                 \
    R"(^((?:[^\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\\;]|\\\\|\\;)*);)"   \
    R"((L|P|D|DN|R|W|LS|PS|RS|LU|PU|RU|LK|PK|RK|F);)" \
    R"(((?:[^\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\\;]|\\\\|\\;)*);)"    \
    R"(((?:[^\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\\;]|\\\\|\\;)*);)"    \
    R"(((?:[^\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\\;]|\\\\|\\;|\\:)*))" \
    R"((?:;((?:[^\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\\;])"             \
    R"(|\\\\|\\;|\';\')*))?$)"

struct results_t {
    std::string address, command, client, param, value, error;
};

static const std::regex pattern{DEFAULT_REGEX};

void std_regex(const std::string &payload, results_t &res) {
    std::smatch pieces;
    bool matched = std::regex_match(payload, pieces, pattern);

    if (!matched || pieces.size() != 7) {
        throw std::runtime_error("ERROR");
    }

    res = { pieces[1], pieces[2], pieces[3], pieces[4], pieces[5], pieces[6] };
}

static std::string const payload = "zzz\\\\bbbb;L;babaa;bubu\\;cc;vvvv;asdff";

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("testcase", [](/*nonius::chronometer cm*/) {
    results_t res;
    std_regex(payload, res);
})
```

Comment: Aside from other benchmarking issues, you are testing a standard Iibrary component, not a compiler. The two machines probably have different library versions.

Comment: Yup. It's libc++ against libstdc++. No need for different machines though. Mind you, it's the OP doing that, so perhaps you meant to post your comment at the question?

Comment: oops, i have corrected the issue with std::set in my original post

Comment: Yep, commenting using an android is imprecise :-) The point was that just changing g++ to clang++ doesn't change which library you use.

Comment: @byteunit I've updated my answer. There are many subtleties to benchmarking, I heartily recommend the (awesome) https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius library

Comment: Added clang/libstdc++ for good measure. Long story short, _yes different implementations have different performance. Compilers hardly involved._

Comment: sehe: for future reference, I think it would be useful to identify the libstdc++ and libc++ versions, not just the versions of the compilers.

Comment: @rici I have no clue how to find these. They're the standard versions packaged with gcc version 5.1.0 (Ubuntu 5.1.0-0ubuntu11~14.04.1) 
and Ubuntu clang version 3.6.0-2ubuntu1~trusty1 (tags/RELEASE_360/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.0) respectively (could be 1.0~svn199600-1)